# "We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Tags: discussion

Why did I get a ban for providing an answer to a question which was helpful.

1. Firstly I am a new user to superuser.
2. I did a question a few years ago.
3. I came back and thought I would answer a question in return
   and the next question I tried to answer I got banned.

I tried to get in touch with someone to lift the ban but there is no one no contact to respond to

Answer (score 11):

You're answer banned since you have three deleted answers - one of them was not an answer at all, one was an answer to an off topic question (which is best left unanswered) and the last was marked as spam (and had a link to a keygen *and* a spammy looking site). I'd recommend looking through existing, well received answers to understand what makes a good answer. It certainly looks like with the existing answers, it is pretty difficult for me to suggest improvements, and the answer ban was working as designed.

You've also originally posted this question on the wrong part of the site (which we've migrated) - I've migrated it for you. To me, this indicates you probably should take a closer look at our help pages, to understand the way the things work here.

Now, that we've talked about the reasons for the ban, I'd point you at [the appropriate, official FAQ on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), and there's literally no manual way for lifting a post ban.

In theory, you could attempt to improve your existing, deleted questions and flag for undeletion and that's the officially recommended way to do so.

Comment: Thank You Kindly Sir